[Google Cloud Run][gRpc] Unable to reach to container from postman request
Tried hosting gRpc container in google cloud run. Enabled http/2 traffic and allowUnauthenticated traffic.
In container logs, I can see gRpc service starting and listening on port. However, when I try to invoke the service from postman I'm getting response as "Call Cancelled" without https in url and couldn't invoke method when trying to call with https:// as protocol.
Below is yaml configuration of cloud run service
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: '165746377172'
  selfLink: /apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/165746377172/services/my-service
  uid: f0188bd4-e5bb-4ab9-ba48-6d33f46251e0
  resourceVersion: kjhkjhk
  generation: 2
  creationTimestamp: '2024-05-28T09:03:56.993590Z'
  labels:
    run.googleapis.com/satisfiesPzs: 'true'
    cloud.googleapis.com/location: asia-south1
  annotations:
    serving.knative.dev/creator: sainageswar@gmail.com
    serving.knative.dev/lastModifier: sainageswar@gmail.com
    run.googleapis.com/client-name: cloud-console
    run.googleapis.com/operation-id: 8a00ba77-7c0f-4267-9982-caaf4eb4bf81
    run.googleapis.com/ingress: all
    run.googleapis.com/ingress-status: all
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        client.knative.dev/nonce: 8fe5a91f-6d44-465e-9e6e-6bde389112d5
        run.googleapis.com/startupProbeType: Default
      annotations:
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '3'
        run.googleapis.com/client-name: cloud-console
        run.googleapis.com/startup-cpu-boost: 'true'
    spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      timeoutSeconds: 300
      serviceAccountName: 165746377172-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
      containers:
      - name: potter
        image: docker.io/myImage
        ports:
        - name: h2c
          containerPort: 50051
        env:
        - name: AZURE_TENANT_ID
          value: xyz
        - name: AZURE_CLIENT_ID
          value: abc
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 512Mi
        startupProbe:
          timeoutSeconds: 240
          periodSeconds: 240
          failureThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 50051
  traffic:
  - percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
status:
  observedGeneration: 2
  conditions:
  - type: Ready
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2024-05-28T09:49:02.523953Z'
  - type: ConfigurationsReady
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2024-05-28T09:03:57.100438Z'
  - type: RoutesReady
    status: 'True'
    lastTransitionTime: '2024-05-28T09:49:02.477867Z'
  latestReadyRevisionName: hjgjhgj
  latestCreatedRevisionName: iouoiuoiu
  traffic:
  - revisionName: hgjhgjhg
    percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
  url: https://bnma-el.a.run.app
  address:
    url: https://bnma-el.a.run.app


Without the exact call and detailed error it's difficult to debug your issue. Are you trying to access the Cloud Run endpoint using the service's [status|address].url on port 443? Some gRPC clients expect the scheme (https://) and others do not; I don't use Postman and so don't know what it expects.
